# unique melt and pivot crosstab format with a groupby using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset where I would like for some values to become column headers, as well as a crosstab format.

data

```
year    qtr     ID  type    growth  re     nondd_re   se_re or
2024    2024Q1  NY  aa      3.18    1.14    0         0     0
2024    2024Q2  NY  aa      2.1     1.14    0         0     0
2024    2024Q1  NY  dd      6.26    3.07    3.07      0     0
2024    2024Q2  NY  dd      4.13    3.07    3.07      0     0
2024    2024Q1  CA  aa      0       0       0         0     0
2024    2024Q2  CA  aa      0.03    0       0         0     0
2024    2024Q1  CA  dd      0       0       0         0     0
2024    2024Q2  CA  dd      0.06    0       0         0     0
```

desired

```
ID  type       type 2024Q1  2024Q2
NY  growth     dd   6.26    4.13
NY  nond_ re   dd   3.07    3.07
NY  se_re      dd   0       0
NY  or         dd   0       0
NY  re         dd   3.07    3.07
NY  growth     aa   3.18    2.1
NY  nond_ re   aa   0       0
NY  se_re      aa   0       0
NY  or         aa   0       0
NY  re         aa   1.14    1.14
CA  growth     dd   0       0.6
CA  nond_ re   dd   0       0
CA  se_re      dd   0       0
CA  or         dd   0       0
CA  re         dd   0       0
CA  growth     aa   0       0.3
CA  nond_ re   aa   0       0
CA  se_re      aa   0       0
CA  or         aa   0       0
CA  re         aa   0       0
```

doing

```
# Melt the dataframe to transform metrics columns into rows


    melted_df = df.melt(id_vars=["year", "qtr", "ID", "type"], var_name="type", value_name="value")

# Pivot the melted dataframe

    pivot_df = melted_df.pivot_table(index=["ID","type"], columns="qtr", values="value", fill_value=0)
    
# Reset index to turn multi-index into columns

    pivot_df = pivot_df.reset_index()
```

The issue is that all of the values aren't getting. The above code produces output with missing values
Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to `set_index()` + `stack()`/`unstack()`:

```py
out = (
    df.set_index(["year", "qtr", "ID", "type"])
    .stack()
    .unstack("qtr")
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"level_3": "type2"})
    .rename_axis(columns=None, index=None)
)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
    year  ID type     type2  2024Q1  2024Q2
0   2024  CA   aa    growth    0.00    0.03
1   2024  CA   aa        re    0.00    0.00
2   2024  CA   aa  nondd_re    0.00    0.00
3   2024  CA   aa     se_re    0.00    0.00
4   2024  CA   aa        or    0.00    0.00
5   2024  CA   dd    growth    0.00    0.06
6   2024  CA   dd        re    0.00    0.00
7   2024  CA   dd  nondd_re    0.00    0.00
8   2024  CA   dd     se_re    0.00    0.00
9   2024  CA   dd        or    0.00    0.00
10  2024  NY   aa    growth    3.18    2.10
11  2024  NY   aa        re    1.14    1.14
12  2024  NY   aa  nondd_re    0.00    0.00
13  2024  NY   aa     se_re    0.00    0.00
14  2024  NY   aa        or    0.00    0.00
15  2024  NY   dd    growth    6.26    4.13
16  2024  NY   dd        re    3.07    3.07
17  2024  NY   dd  nondd_re    3.07    3.07
18  2024  NY   dd     se_re    0.00    0.00
19  2024  NY   dd        or    0.00    0.00
```

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

use `melt` & `pivot`

```
tmp = df.melt(id_vars=["year", "qtr", "ID", "type"])
m1 = {'NY': 0, 'CA': 1,  'dd': 0, 'aa': 1, 'growth': 0, 'nondd_re': 1, 'se_re': 2, 'or': 3, 're': 4}
out = (tmp.pivot(index=['ID', 'variable', 'type'], columns=['qtr'], values='value')
          .reset_index().rename_axis('', axis=1)
          .sort_values(['ID', 'type', 'variable'], key=lambda x: x.map(m1))
          .rename({'variable' : 'type'}, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True))
```

out:

```
    ID      type type  2024Q1  2024Q2
0   NY    growth   dd    6.26    4.13
1   NY  nondd_re   dd    3.07    3.07
2   NY     se_re   dd    0.00    0.00
3   NY        or   dd    0.00    0.00
4   NY        re   dd    3.07    3.07
5   NY    growth   aa    3.18    2.10
6   NY  nondd_re   aa    0.00    0.00
7   NY     se_re   aa    0.00    0.00
8   NY        or   aa    0.00    0.00
9   NY        re   aa    1.14    1.14
10  CA    growth   dd    0.00    0.06
11  CA  nondd_re   dd    0.00    0.00
12  CA     se_re   dd    0.00    0.00
13  CA        or   dd    0.00    0.00
14  CA        re   dd    0.00    0.00
15  CA    growth   aa    0.00    0.03
16  CA  nondd_re   aa    0.00    0.00
17  CA     se_re   aa    0.00    0.00
18  CA        or   aa    0.00    0.00
19  CA        re   aa    0.00    0.00
```

Although you accurately generated the desired output, I think it is not a good habit to create columns with the same name. Additionally, the sorting order you want is not clear.

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'year': [2024, 2024, 2024, 2024, 2024, 2024, 2024, 2024], 
         'qtr': ['2024Q1', '2024Q2', '2024Q1', '2024Q2', '2024Q1', '2024Q2', '2024Q1', '2024Q2'], 
         'ID': ['NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA'], 
         'type': ['aa', 'aa', 'dd', 'dd', 'aa', 'aa', 'dd', 'dd'], 
         'growth': [3.18, 2.1, 6.26, 4.13, 0.0, 0.03, 0.0, 0.06], 
         're': [1.14, 1.14, 3.07, 3.07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
         'nondd_re': [0.0, 0.0, 3.07, 3.07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
         'se_re': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
         'or': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```